# How to remove all <img> tag from column using a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table name `wp_posts` and in `post_content` column there is a description of my posts (in HTML).

I would like to have a query that searches in `post_content` column and selects the tag starting with `<img class="aligncenter` and ending with this `">` and remove whole tag.

**This :**

```
<div class="col-lg-6>
<a href="#"><img class="aligncenter size-full" src="https://example.com/Guardians-Alien-Hunter.jpg" alt="random" /></a>
</div>
```

**Would become this:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6>
<a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

My MYSQL version is 5.7.28.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_REPLACE` provides one option:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '<img.*?/>', '')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<img%';
```

On earlier versions of MySQL which do not support `REGEXP_REPLACE`, we can try using the base string functions:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(
    LEFT(post_content, LOCATE('<img', post_content) - 1), 
    SUBSTRING(post_content, LOCATE('/>', post_content, LOCATE('<img', post_content) + 4) + 2))
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<img%';
```

But note that the above 5.7 version is much more error prone than the regex version for 8+.  Actually, for editing HTML content which might be nested, even regex is not suitable, and you should be using a parser, probably outside your database.

Comment: Thank you but my MYSQL version is 5.7.28. any other way?

Comment: @Heisenberg I have given you an option for 5.7, which hopefully eliminates some uncertainty for you.